# GCM unregister causing the application to crash

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I've implemented GCM notifications on my app. I am now trying to un-register the app when the user logs out. I am using the following code. When this code executes, it causes the application to crash with the following logcat:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.<init>()' is inaccessible to class 'com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd' (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd' appears in /data/app/com.example.packagename-1/base.apk)
    at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.zzeb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.zaryans.updatedepoultry.WelcomeActivity$11.onItemClick(WelcomeActivity.java:469)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1145)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3066)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3903)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here is the code:

```
InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(WelcomeActivity.this);
try {
   instanceID.deleteInstanceID();
   Utility.logCatMsg("Logged Out Success!!!");
} catch (IOException e) {
   Utility.logCatMsg("Exception while logging out: "+e.getMessage());
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: For me, compiling facebooksdk created this problem

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I was with same problem after update the support library to 25.0.0 .
For me after update the below libs,in the app gradle file, the problem gone.

```
compile("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1")
compile("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1")
compile("com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.1")
```

Comment: It helped me. Thanks alot :-)

Comment: I tried to update but doesn't resolve anything. Still the same error

Comment: i tried this way but no luck can you please help me here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40904466/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-method-void-android-support-v4-content

Comment: What's the google-services plugin version that you used? I got version conflict error while trying to update 9.6.1.

Comment: @pasanbuddhika I used version 3.0.0

Answer (score 4):

Update the google play services to the latest version (9.8.0) after updating the android support library to 25.0.0
I had the same problem this morning and this worked for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this will solve your problem, but it's always a good idea to pass the application `Context` to third party frameworks, rather than `Activity` instances, as the latter can lead to memory leaks. Try this instead:

```
InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: I tired, but no luck :-(

Answer (score 0):

use dependencies in the given way

```
compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1") {
        force = true;
    }
    compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1") {
        force = true;
    }
    compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1") {
        force = true;
    }
    compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1') {
        force = true;
    }
    compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1') {
        force = true;
    }
```