# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.content

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, build.gradle

I updated playservice in my sdk and I got this error. And I am not able to access GCM Token. Before update sdk my project work perfectly.

I waste my whole day in it but not found any solution. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40218025/gcm-unregister-causing-the-application-to-crash)  but gettting error in this dependencies `com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.0`

Here is my **logcat**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.<init>()' is inaccessible to class 'com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd' (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd' appears in /data/data/com.hwindiapp.passenger/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-iid-9.0.0_b51865a18dbfbfb3651aaa54856c955adf1e354f-classes.dex)
   at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.zzeC(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)
   at com.mainProfile.classFiles.RegisterFbLoginResCallBack$registerFBUser.processGCMID_user(RegisterFbLoginResCallBack.java:166)
   at com.mainProfile.classFiles.RegisterFbLoginResCallBack$registerFBUser.doInBackground(RegisterFbLoginResCallBack.java:219)
   at com.mainProfile.classFiles.RegisterFbLoginResCallBack$registerFBUser.doInBackground(RegisterFbLoginResCallBack.java:153)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
12-01 12:23:59.553 18157-18703/com.hwindiapp.passenger E/ACRA: Not adding buildConfig to log. Class Not found : com.VolleyLibFiles.BuildConfig. Please configure 'buildConfigClass' in your ACRA config
12-01 12:24:00.013 18157-19059/com.hwindiapp.passenger E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
 Process: com.hwindiapp.passenger, PID: 18157
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.<init>()' is inaccessible to class 'com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd' (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd' appears in /data/data/com.hwindiapp.passenger/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-iid-9.0.0_b51865a18dbfbfb3651aaa54856c955adf1e354f-classes.dex)
     at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.zzeC(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)
     at com.mainProfile.classFiles.RegisterFbLoginResCallBack$registerFBUser.processGCMID_user(RegisterFbLoginResCallBack.java:166)
     at com.mainProfile.classFiles.RegisterFbLoginResCallBack$registerFBUser.doInBackground(RegisterFbLoginResCallBack.java:219)
     at com.mainProfile.classFiles.RegisterFbLoginResCallBack$registerFBUser.doInBackground(RegisterFbLoginResCallBack.java:153)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
```

Showing error in this line of code

```
 InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(mContext);
            GCMregistrationId = instanceID.getToken(CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID, GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE,
                    null);
```

And here is my **gradle**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'hwindi'
            keyPassword '123456'
            storeFile file('D:/Company Projects/Hwindi/Project 2/Play_KeyStore/HwindiKeyStore.jks')
            storePassword '123456'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hwindiapp.passenger"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 12
        versionName "1.12"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libcardioDecider.so'
        exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libcardioRecognizer.so'
        exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libcardioRecognizer_tegra2.so'
        exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libopencv_core.so'
        exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libopencv_imgproc.so'
        exclude 'lib/armeabi/libcardioDecider.so'
        exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libcardioDecider.so'
        exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libcardioRecognizer.so'
        exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libcardioRecognizer_tegra2.so'
        exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.so'
        exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_imgproc.so'
        exclude 'lib/mips/libcardioDecider.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86/libcardioDecider.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86/libcardioRecognizer.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86/libcardioRecognizer_tegra2.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86/libopencv_core.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86/libopencv_imgproc.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/libcardioDecider.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/libcardioRecognizer.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/libcardioRecognizer_tegra2.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/libopencv_core.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/libopencv_imgproc.so'
    }
    configurations.all {
        /*resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
            force 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
            force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
        }*/
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile ('com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.8') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.13.3'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.mukesh:permissions:1.0.3'
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Please check your [declared dependencies](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#dependencies). As discussed in the given [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#dependencies) there are three different types of direct dependencies in the app/ module's `build.gradle` file.

Sample dependencies are as follows:

```
android {...}
...
dependencies {
    // The 'compile' configuration tells Gradle to add the dependency to the
    // compilation classpath and include it in the final package.

    // Dependency on the "mylibrary" module from this project
    compile project(":mylibrary")

    // Remote binary dependency
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'

    // Local binary dependency
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Furthermore, as answered by [@Diego Giorgini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37337203) in a related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312340/incompatibleclasschangeerror-after-updating-to-android-build-tools-25-1-6-gcm),

> The issue you are experiencing is due to an incompatibility between
> `play-services / firebase sdk v9.0.0` and  `com.android.support:appcompat-v7 >= 24` (the version released with android-N sdk)

With this, you may want to try the suggested fix:

> You should be able to fix it by targeting an earlier version of the support library. Like:
>
> `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'`

You may want to also check the other suggestions in the following SO posts:

- [IncompatibleClassChangeError after updating to Android Build Tools 25.1.6 GCM / FCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312340/incompatibleclasschangeerror-after-updating-to-android-build-tools-25-1-6-gcm)
- [Android Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) token generation crash after Firebase-related Google Play Services update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337393/android-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-token-generation-crash-after-firebase-relat).

Comment: Thanks for reply but i solve it. by removing api 25 in sdk as well as build tools and change facebook version to 4.16.+

Comment: Apparently, it compiles without errors if you don't include the appcomapt dependancy, but it wont work without it, and it doesn't tell you that this is a problem... Yeeesh

Comment: Doesn't seem to work still, sorry. Only solution is to update build tools and complie sdk version...

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem after some digging I found out that facebook sdk was depending on the new version of *google support libraries* than I have compiled on.

You can check the dependencies with gradle command

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

Ensure that all the dependency libraries has same version.
If not then you can exclude that dependency using

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'){
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

then later add the required the dependency you have compiled your project on, In my case

> compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'

Answer (score 0):

Set a API version check of > 22 cause I got the same issue

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setProgress(int, boolean)' is inaccessible to class
```

and I fixed it like:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 22)
    progressBar.setProgress(currentProgress, true);
else
    progressBar.setProgress(currentProgress);
```

check here [setProgress Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36946749)

Answer (score -1):

I have Android Studio 2.3 and my problem was solved by uninstalling the "**Android Support Library (Obsolete)**" from SDK Tools.